# `static` keyword inside function?

Tags: php, function, static, keyword

I was looking at the source for Drupal 7, and I found some things I hadn't seen before. I did some initial looking in the php manual, but it didn't explain these examples.

What does the keyword `static` do to a variable inside a function?

```
function module_load_all($bootstrap = FALSE) {
    static $has_run = FALSE
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: It's probably my favorite php feature!

Answer (score 199, accepted):

It makes the function remember the value of the given variable (`$has_run` in your example) between multiple calls.

You could use this for different purposes, for example:

```
function doStuff() {
  static $cache = null;

  if ($cache === null) {
     $cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
  }

  // code using $cache
}
```

In this example, the `if` would only be executed once. Even if multiple calls to `doStuff` would occur.

Comment: Also, if the function has run once, it will not reset the value of `$cache` to `null` on later calls, right?

Comment: @user151841 `$cache` will only be reset between requests. So yes, it will *not be reset* on laters calls in the same request (or execution of the script).

Comment: @Muhammad because that's just what the keywords [static](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php) does.

Comment: I believe `if` condition check `$cache === null` would be executed every time this function is called, thought not if's block code `$cache = '..'` would be executed.

Comment: what happens if the function is a method in a class, is the static variable shared between instances?

Comment: @santiagoarizti check the next answer by Yang.

Comment: Oh I see, so yes, behaves like a static property, not really useful for OOP then, more like the option to have a static variable in a function that is not a class method.

Comment: You need to understand the meaning of 'Static': 'Static' means that the property is 'Static' in memory: It has a fixed allocated block in memory (though with PHP, the concept of blocks of memory is bit.. dynamic, so take this lightly). This means that if the function runs and the block of static memory is set (during the function execution), the block of memory won't reset during a second or subsequent execution times, as that memory is allocated 'statically' for that variable in that function.

Comment: Otherwise, without the static declaration, when the function is re-executed, a full new function instance will be loaded somewhere else in memory, with the variables (being set on a new block of memory) being reset.

Answer (score 111):

Seems like nobody mentioned so far, that static variables inside different instances of the same class remain their state. So be careful when writing OOP code.

Consider this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function call()
    {
        static $test = 0;

        $test++;
        echo $test . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}

$a = new Foo();
$a->call(); // 1
$a->call(); // 2
$a->call(); // 3


$b = new Foo();
$b->call(); // 4
$b->call(); // 5
```

If you want a static variable to remember its state only for current class instance, you'd better stick to a class property, like this:

```
class Bar
{
    private $test = 0;

    public function call()
    {
        $this->test++;
        echo $this->test . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}


$a = new Bar();
$a->call(); // 1
$a->call(); // 2
$a->call(); // 3


$b = new Bar();
$b->call(); // 1
$b->call(); // 2
```

Comment: Ouch! This has bitten me more than once. I expected the static to apply to the instance only, providing memoization; but that was wrong way of thinking, because "static" in the context of classes means for the class as a whole. Properties, methods, AND variables.

Answer (score 15):

Given the following example:

```
function a($s){
    static $v = 10;
    echo $v;
    $v = $s;
}
```

First call of

```
a(20);
```

will output `10`, then `$v` to be `20`. The variable `$v` is not garbage collected after the function ends, as it is a static (non-dynamic) variable. The variable will stay within its scope until the script totally ends.

Therefore, the following call of

```
a(15);
```

will then output `20`, and then set `$v` to be `15`.

Answer (score 11):

Static works the same way as it does in a class.  The variable is shared across all instances of a function.  In your particular example, once the function is run, $has_run is set to TRUE.  All future runs of the function will have $has_run = TRUE.  This is particularly useful in recursive functions (as an alternative to passing the count).

> A static variable exists only in a
>   local function scope, but it does not
>   lose its value when program execution
>   leaves this scope.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 7):

To expand on [the answer of Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function#27879260)

If you extend a class with static variables, the individual extended classes will hold their "own" referenced static that's shared between instances.

```
<?php
class base {
     function calc() {
        static $foo = 0;
        $foo++;
        return $foo;
     }
}

class one extends base {
    function e() {
        echo "one:".$this->calc().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class two extends base {
    function p() {
        echo "two:".$this->calc().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$x = new one();
$y = new two();
$x_repeat = new one();

$x->e();
$y->p();
$x->e();
$x_repeat->e();
$x->e();
$x_repeat->e();
$y->p();
```

outputs:

> one:1
>     **two**:1
>     one:2
>     *one*:3  <-- x_repeat
>     one:4
>     *one*:5  <-- x_repeat
>     **two**:2

http://ideone.com/W4W5Qv

Answer (score 3):

static variable in a function means that no matter how many times you call the function, there's only 1 variable.

```
<?php

class Foo{
    protected static $test = 'Foo';
    function yourstatic(){
        static $test = 0;
        $test++;
        echo $test . "\n"; 
    }

    function bar(){
        $test = 0;
        $test++;
        echo $test . "\n";
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->yourstatic(); // 1
$f->yourstatic(); // 2
$f->yourstatic(); // 3
$f->bar(); // 1
$f->bar(); // 1
$f->bar(); // 1

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a function, `static` means that the variable will retain its value each time the function is called during the life of the page load.

Therefore in the example you've given, if you call a function twice, if it set `$has_run` to `true`, then the function would be able to know that it had previously been called because `$has_run` would still be equal to `true` when the function starts the second time.

The usage of the `static` keyword in this context is explained in the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php