# Access private value in namespaced public function

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a value that only needs to be calculated once. I can't use `const` to declare it though because I need to run some functions to calculate initially. I'd like to be able to store it in somewhat protected way and access it in a (namespaced) global function. What's is a good pattern to do this? Here's what I have:

**Option 1** - works well but only for constants so I can't use this:

```
<?php 
namespace my;

const PREFIX = 'example';

/**
 * my\get_prefix()
 */
function get_prefix () {
    return PREFIX;
}
```

**Option 2** - namespaced function accesses value from preconfigured namespaced public static class:

```
<?php 
namespace my;

class Hash {
    public static $prefix;

    public static function configure () {
        self::$prefix = call_user_func(function () {
            // calculate and return a string 
        });
    }
}

Hash::configure();

/**
 * my\get_prefix()
 */
function get_prefix () {
    return Hash::$prefix;
}
```

**Option 3** - similar to #2, but here configuration runs the first time `get_prefix` is called, and is checked to be a string each time:

```
<?php 
namespace my;

class Hash {
    public static $prefix;
}

/**
 * my\get_prefix()
 */
function get_prefix () {
    if ( is_string(Hash::$prefix) )
        return Hash::$prefix;

    Hash::$prefix = call_user_func(function () {
        // calculate and return a string 
    });

    return Hash::$prefix;
}
```

**Option 4** - totally protected by use of static method / private var, but adds an extra function call if called via `my\get_prefix()`:

```
<?php 
namespace my;

class Hash {
    private static $prefix;

    public static function configure () {
        if ( isset(self::$prefix) ) return;
        self::$prefix = call_user_func(function () {
            // calculate and return a string 
        });
    }

    public static function get_prefix () {
        return self::$prefix;
    }
}

Hash::configure();

/**
 * my\get_prefix()
 */
function get_prefix () {
    return Hash::get_prefix();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I just discovered that the `static` keyword to can be used to create a private scope that can be re-accessed each time the function is called:

```
<?php
namespace my;

/**
 * my\get_prefix()
 */
function get_prefix () {
    static $prefix; 
    if ( !isset($prefix) ) {
        // calculate $prefix (only runs once)
    }
    return $prefix;
}
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function) and [php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it by combining option #3 and #4 (lazy loaded):

```
class Hash 
{
    private static $prefix;

    public static function getPrefix()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$prefix)) {
            // the value is not set yet, so generate it
            self::$prefix = function_that_generates_prefix();
        }
        return self::$prefix;
    }
}

$prefix = Hash::getPrefix();
```

Comment: Cool like a combo of #3 and #4 and w/o the namespace. I don't need the namespace, I just felt like there should be a way to do it with them LOL and that the usage would be cleaner. Of course still could add the namespace to this.

Comment: @ryanve Yes, I didn't think the namespace added much to the discussion so I've left it out of my answer; it would work in either situation.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this looks like a great candidate for lazy loading.

```
namespace My;

class Hash
{
    protected static $prefix;

    public static function getPrefix()
    {
        if (null === self::$prefix) {
            self::$prefix = calculate_and_return_a_string();
        }
        return self::$prefix;
    }
}

$prefix = My\Hash::getPrefix();
```

A couple of things to note.  First, I changed the visibility of `My\Hash::$prefix` from `private` to `protected`.  Generally, unless there is a really good reason to use `private`, I prefer to stick with `protected` variables.

Second, you may want to reevaluate the relationship between the `My\Hash` class and the `calculate_and_return_a_string()` function (you used `call_user_func`).  Maybe find a way to inject the calculated value, which will decouple the class from the function and remove the extra dependency.

Lastly, it might be worth it to reevaluate whether you need to put this in its own class at all.  If you are only using it to store and register a single variable, it might be better to use a registry or something similar.  Of course, I can't see the entire context, so only you will know if this is applicable.