# How to create an enclosed function in php?

Tags: php

I want to write a program in php, and I need to make an enclosed function that can be called from the main body, but it has its own variables, subfunctions, and is completely independent from its surroundings.

Basically I need something like this to work:

```
$variable=10;  //variables defined here need to be available everywhere, except in bigfunction

function smallfunction(){
    echo $variable;  //will print variable defined in main body
}

function bigfunction($input) {   
    /* this will be the big function, that needs to have its own global variables and functions. It cant see any variables defined outside of this function. Any function and variable defined in this function will never be used outside of this function, and any function or variable defined outside this function will never be used inside this function. The only interaction with its surroundings will be in its arguments and output(return) of this bigfunction. It will receive certain input, and return outcome. It will need to be run repeatedly, as it will be called rather often from main body, every time it will run independently of previous runs of this function.
    */

    $variable = $input * 5;  
    /* this variable needs to be independent of the $variable in main body, even if it has same name. It also needs to be accessible in any other function declared inside of bigfunction. Basically it has to be global variable inside bigfunction.
    */ 

    function subfunction(){
        echo $variable; //will print $variable from bigfunction
        $variable = $variable - 25; //this will change $variable value.
    }
    subfunction();
    return $variable; //bigfunction will return value equal to $input*5-25.                       
} //here the program can forget everything that happened inside bigfunction, including function declarations and defined variables.

//now these function will be called

smallfunction();  //will print value of $variable in main body. In this case it will be "10".

bigfunction(5); //will print "25" (5*5), and return 0 (25-25).

smallfunction(); //still prints 10, since $variable in main body hasn't changed.

$variable = bigfunction(8); //will print "40" (8*5), and return 15 (40-25).

smallfunction(); //this time it will print "15", since $variable value has changed with previous command.
```

I have no idea how to make a variable global only inside a certain function, and I also have no idea how to make the bigfunction run more than once, since if I try to run it repeatedly like its in the example, it says I can't redeclare the subfunction inside it.

Any help with these problems would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. sorry for kinda messy formatting, this is my first time writing on this page, and the formatting in here is kinda messy.

Comment: Indent your code by 4 spaces to make it format, or use the {} button to do it for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`static\` keyword inside function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may wish to use the `global $variable;` keyword like so:

```
$variable=10; //variables defined here need to be available everywhere, except in bigfunction

function smallfunction(){
     global $variable;
     echo $variable;  //will print variable defined in main body
}
```

Comment: Yes this code flow is not exactly excellent (as in this situation especially, it creates a rather confusing result making it possibly awkward to debug if overused), so a different set of variables would be better; Using global answers the question rather than proposing an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHP 's anonymous functions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
function bigFunction($input, Closure $callback) {
    $variable = $input * 5;
    $callback($variable);

    return $variable;
}

// will output 25;
echo bigFunction(10, function($input) {
    $input -= 25;
    return $input;
});
```

That 's a simple example. The same you can do in a more complex way with objctes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever consider just using a class to represent what you need? Closures may be what you are looking for, however, then I read you want to have "subfunctions". This a problem that can be solved with OOP. If this functionality can be reused elsewhere in your code, or needs to interact with other parts of your system, consider creating it as a usual class instead.