# Calling a method only one time

Tags: php, php-7

I'm working in a custom framework.

I've a class:

```
<?php

class group extends \something\some
{
  public function mymethod() {
     //code
     return $output;
  }

  public static who() {
    //I've a DB query here returning an array
    return $query-result;
  }
}
```

Then in a page of frontend I've:

```
$group = new group();
foreach ($users as $user) {
      //mycode
      $who = $group::who();
}
```

But in this way I generate **num users x 1 queries**, with 20 users 20 queries.

I can hook only inside the foreach, then I want to know if there is a way to grab this array (method who()) only one time also if I call it inside a foreach.

Comment: Besides a syntax error, I don't see why you can't call `who()` above the foreach?

Comment: There is an hooking system that I can use to extend framework functionality and there are no hook outside foreach.

Comment: Doesn´t make much sence to me, that you cant call it outside the loop. What happens when you do? You dont even give anything from the loop to the `who` method.

Comment: I'm developing an addon and I can't edit the framework file. For this reason I can hook only inside the loop, where there is the HOOK. Obviously if I edit the framework file and I call who() outside the foreach it works, but I can't edit the code in this way.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how the hook comes into play in any way in the code shown. Unless the bit you've skipped with the `//mycode` comment is doing anything with `$group`, there should be no reason at all that you can't move the `$who` line outside the `foreach`. Unless the `foreach` loop itself is in the framework file that you can't edit? Doesn't seem so, since that's where you've indicated you have "my code". Maybe showing more code would help? This is certainly not a MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result from your database in a static variable inside the method (or in the class). You fill it only once when it isn't loaded yet. Any future call will use the already fetched data. The code will look something like that (answer from [`static` keyword inside function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function/6189021#6189021)):

> ```
> function doStuff() {
>     static $cache = null;
>
>     if ($cache === null) {
>         $cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
>     }
>
>     // code using $cache
> }
> ```