# Incremental number on factory, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-factory

I have a factory that is called several times, but on `contract_year` column I get the same value.

```
$factory->define(ContractYear::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $contract = Contract::orderByDesc('id')->first();
    $contract_year = ContractYear::select('contract_year')->orderByDesc('id')->value('contract_year');
    if($contract_year == null){
        $contract_year = 2019;
    }

    return [
        'contract_id'                   => $contract->id,
        'contract_year'                 => $contract_year++,
        'licensed_users'                => $faker->randomDigit,
    ];

});
```

I call it from here..

```
 $u->contracts()->saveMany(factory(Contract::class, rand(1, 5))->create()->each(function ($contract){
     $contract->years()->saveMany(factory(ContractYear::class, $contract->number_of_years)->create());            
}));
```

Comment: This wont work unless you run the factory once at a time. The factories are bulkinserting, so each $contract_year will be null, then 2019, then 2020 after ++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static`

```
$factory->define(ContractYear::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $contract_year;
    
    $contract = Contract::orderByDesc('id')->first();
    if(!$contract_year) {
        $contract_year =  ContractYear::select('contract_year')->orderByDesc('id')->value('contract_year') ?? 2019;
    }

    return [
        'contract_id'                   => $contract->id,
        'contract_year'                 => $contract_year++,
        'licensed_users'                => $faker->randomDigit,
    ];

});
```

Reference: [`static` keyword inside function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function)

Comment: I tried this and I get "Constant expression contains invalid operations"

Comment: You only wrote `static`, not `public static` right ? Also, try to place `static $contract_year = 2019;` before `$contrat  = ...`  and remove `= ContractYear::...` to see this works? I have exactly this in one of my project and it's working.

Comment: Yes that way I don't get error, but the increment is for  each contract. So If I have 4 rows for 1 contract all are (2019, 2019...), and on the next contract I get (2020)..and so on. Is not incremental for the same contract.

Comment: I have uptaded my answer. Try this way. IRC correctly you can't assign a variable or a function result when declaring a variable property.

Comment: I get no errors, but the increment is done on each contract, not for each row assigned to a contract, like I described above.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want as end result.

Comment: I have updated to something that makes much more sense to me. But I still don't understand how should do the contract_year

Comment: I have a relationship one to many, one contract can have many contract_years, and the contract_years should be incremental. ex: Contract 1 have ContractYears (2019,2020), Contract 2 have ContractYears(2019,2020,2021), Contract 3 have ContractYears(2019). Right now I get (2019,2019) , (2020,2020,2020),  (2021).

Answer (score 0):

Attach a counter to `$this`

```
$factory->define(ContractYear::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $this->sequences = $this->sequences ?? [];

    $contract = Contract::orderByDesc('id')->first();

    $group = $contract->id ?? 0;

    $this->sequences[$group] = $this->sequences[$group] ?? 2019;

    return [
        'contract_id'                   => $contract->id,
        'contract_year'                 => $this->sequences[$group]++,
        'licensed_users'                => $faker->randomDigit,
    ];

});
```

Might be worth looking into Laravel 8 new Model factories for more explicit object oriented approach

Comment: I get this error :"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::$contract_year"

Comment: Ok, almost there. Is incremented, but for all contracts, is not reset to 2019 when it gets to next contract. How can I set 2019 as first value for each Contract?

Comment: @Beusebiu got it

Comment: Some of them are ok, some are still incremental from (ex: 2025). First 3 contracts are ok, forth one begins with 2023, the fifth is ok, strange behavior.