# Static variable set to null and doesn't get null value each time

Tags: php

I just want to understand what is the purpose of setting static $db variable to null before if statement where it is checked if it's null. Then it will always be null. That's the code for getting PDO database connection from abstract class.

why the **static $db** property does not get the *null* value each time the function get called?

```
    protected static function getDB()
{   
    static $db = null;
    if ($db === null) {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'dbname';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
    
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", 
                          $username, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return $db;
}
```

Comment: static stores the variable on the function itself and it will remember the value between function calls. initially setting it to null is how it will be the first call. If code in the function sets it to something else later, it will be remembered for future calls. This makes it very easy for things like only connecting to the db once, etc.

Comment: You mean if that static variable has a value, it won't get a new value every time I want to change that?

Comment: Correct, the `if` will only run the first time the `getDB` function is called and create a new PDO connection, etc. The second time the `getDB` function is called, it won't override db to null, it will remember the `$db` pdo connection from the first function call. And `getDB` will skip the if statement and just return the `$db` directly. This is a common pattern for implementing singleton within PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`static\` keyword inside function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function)